# how to upload files to server in ionic capacitor (angular) app

Tags: javascript, angular, http, ionic-framework, capacitor

I know of two potential ways:

1. using the web (Angular) HttpClient
   I can not use anything that acts like a browser since I will get CORS issues on native devices. As far as I know there are two ways around CORS:

   - specify the domain+port that you want to allow (for native devices with webview impossible, since they behave differently with a not-accepted "file://" domain)
   - get a proxy server or something like this that I heard. I did not quite understand this so I dropped this idea because of its complexity
2. using the capacitor-community/http Http.uploadFile() method
   I would prefer not using capacitor-community/http since it is not maintained anymore. Let me know if I am wrong and it is still a good idea to use this.
   I would rather use the official CapacitorHttp but I think it doesn't support files yet or does it?

In the CapacitorHttp documentation it says:

#### Large File Support​

Due to the nature of the bridge, parsing and transferring large amount of data from native to the web can cause issues. Support for downloading and uploading files to the native device is planned to be added to the @capacitor/filesystem plugin in the near future.

But this talks specifically about **large** files. Maybe small files can already be transferred?

Or maybe the @capacitor/filesystem can already do this? Or maybe there is another way to solve this?

Comment: I'm doing all right with specifying domain names for CORS in native (tho not port I guess). if I get CORS in PWA I'll get it in native too and vice versa. did you try this and it didn't work?

Comment: I tried setting domain to 'localhost' CORS-header. Was this correct? I had no idea what to set it to. It didn't work, I got an error. In the meantime I ditched this whole idea however. I will try again this week and let u know which error.

Also, I got this from GPT4:
"In the context of a WebView inside a mobile app, the origin is typically set to something like file://, because the HTML, JS, and other assets are usually loaded from the local file system. However, this isn't a domain that you can simply add to a CORS policy on your server."

Maybe this wrong and should just set localhost?